# in Emacs is it possible to have open files in separate tabs like in XEmacs?

Tags: windows, emacs

Is it possible to have in emacs open new documents in tabs like XEmacs and other newer editors do ?

How to do it ? By plugin or some kind of setting in init file ?

Comment: Does buffer switching or creating a new frame not accomplish this same thing? Or do you want a menu bar at the top that shows you the open buffers?

Comment: Yes, menu bar at the top that shows the buffers. Maybe there is a patch for Emacs that ports this function from XEmacs, since these are similar projects ?

Comment: Try the tabbar emacs plugin. I personally don't like tabs since `C-x b` and registers move me around faster than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep it is possible, that package is `elscreen` : http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Elscreen

I like it, I see it as a complement for buffer navigation. It helps separating tasks.

You can install it with el-get or ELPA. Its usage is quite similar to `screen`, the command line utility, except that its prefix key is `C-z` by default.

Enjoy !